# Developer Edition / Platform Starter License - Create webservice in Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, licenses, developer, developer-edition

I would like to create a webservice using Salesforce. Can i do it with free Developer Edition (it will be only for my personal usage, but I might make a profits by using my webservice).

Or I have to buy a Platform Starter License. But wondering if it's provides neccessary for me APEX coding with API callouts.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, you can call your webservice API in a Developer Edition org just fine either way. You would need to read the [Force.com Sites Terms of Use (and Order Form Addendum)](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/forcedotcom-sites-tou.pdf) and [Site.com Terms of Use (and Order Form Addendum)](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/salesforce-sitedotcom-tou.pdf) to see if your use case may be a legal violation or not (and I am not a lawyer, so if you're unclear, make sure you consult one). Note that a Developer Edition org has a pretty severe API limitation compared to a production org, so it may not be suitable for your needs.